# Different results with NumPy percentile and TensorFlow percentile for "nearest" interpolation method

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, percentile

I've noticed that even though NumPy's [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) and TensorFlow Probability's [`tfp.stats.percentile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile) give the same docstring explanation for their "nearest" interpolation method

> This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use when the desired percentile lies between two data points `i < j`:
>
> ...
>
> ‘nearest’: `i` or `j`, whichever is nearest.

they give different results. Below is a minimal working example of what I mean.

### Environment

```
$ "$(which python3)" --version
Python 3.7.5
$ python3 -m venv "${HOME}/.venvs/question"
$ . "${HOME}/.venvs/question/bin/activate"
(question) $ cat requirements.txt
numpy~=1.18
tensorflow~=2.1
tensorflow-probability~=0.9
black
(question) $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Code

```py
# question.py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


def main():
    a = np.array([[10.0, 7.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
    q = 50
    print(f"Flattened array: {a.flatten()}")
    print("NumPy:")
    print(f"\t{q}th percentile (linear): {np.percentile(a, q, interpolation='linear')}")
    print(
        f"\t{q}th percentile (nearest): {np.percentile(a, q, interpolation='nearest')}"
    )

    b = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    print("TensorFlow:")
    print(
        f"\t{q}th percentile (linear): {tfp.stats.percentile(b, q, interpolation='linear')}"
    )
    print(
        f"\t{q}th percentile (nearest): {tfp.stats.percentile(b, q, interpolation='nearest')}"
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which when run gives differing results for the "nearest" interpolation method

```
(question) $ python question.py
Flattened array: [10.  7.  4.  3.  2.  1.]
NumPy:
    50th percentile (linear): 3.5
    50th percentile (nearest): 3.0
TensorFlow:
    50th percentile (linear): 3.5
    50th percentile (nearest): 4.0
```

After poking around the [NumPy v1.18.2 source of the function that `numpy.percentile` is calling](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/df256d0d2f3bc6833699529824781c58f9c6e697/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3846) I'm still confused as to why. It seems that this is due to a rounding decision (given that [NumPy uses `numpy.around`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/df256d0d2f3bc6833699529824781c58f9c6e697/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3882) and [TFP uses `tf.round`](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/356cfddef026b3339b8f2a81e600acd2ff8e22b4/tensorflow_probability/python/stats/quantiles.py#L558)).

Can someone explain to me what is happening to cause the difference? I'd like to make a shim for the functions, but I need to understand the return behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure about the tensorflow implementation (you could link that too), but the looking through the numpy source code you sent: line 3872: `indices = q * (Nx - 1) = 2.5` then line 3882: `indices = around(indices).astype(intp) = 2` ([numpy.around](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) rounds to the nearest even number). Then numpy gets the value at index 2 [3.0]. Perhaps tensorflow uses `round` on the index rather than `around` and so 2.5 becomes 3, therefore giving value [4.0]

Comment: Yes, this is my assumption as well (that is must come down to rounding). I should take a look at the TensorFlow source as well. I've updated the question to reflect that this is clearly (at least I hope) a rounding decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through the source of both, it seems that it is *not* a rounding issue like I first though, but that [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) does the final evaluation on an ascending sorted ndarray, while [`tfp.stats.percentile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile) does it on a descending sorted tensor.

```py
# answer.py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import tensorshape_util
from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import distribution_util


def numpy_src(input, q, axis=0, out=None):
    a = input
    q = np.true_divide(q, 100)  # 0.5
    q = np.asanyarray(q)  # array(0.5)
    q = q[None]  # array([0.5])
    ap = a.flatten()  # array([10.,  7.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.])
    Nx = ap.shape[axis]  # 6
    indices = q * (Nx - 1)  # array([2.5])
    indices = np.around(indices).astype(np.intp)  # array([2])
    ap.partition(indices, axis=axis)  # array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  7., 10.])
    indices = indices[0]  # 2
    r = np.take(ap, indices, axis=axis, out=out)  # 3.0
    print(f"Result of np.percentile source: {r}")


def tensorflow_src(input, q=50, axis=None):
    x = input
    name = "percentile"
    interpolation = "nearest"
    q = tf.cast(q, tf.float64)  # tf.Tensor(50.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
    if axis is None:
        y = tf.reshape(
            x, [-1]
        )  # tf.Tensor([10.  7.  4.  3.  2.  1.], shape=(6,), dtype=float64)
    frac_at_q_or_above = 1.0 - q / 100.0  # tf.Tensor(0.5, shape=(), dtype=float64)
    # _sort_tensor(y)
    # N.B. Here is the difference. Note the sort order is never changed
    sorted_y, _ = tf.math.top_k(
        y, k=tf.shape(y)[-1]
    )  # tf.Tensor([10.  7.  4.  3.  2.  1.], shape=(6,), dtype=float64), _
    tensorshape_util.set_shape(
        sorted_y, y.shape
    )  # tf.Tensor([10.  7.  4.  3.  2.  1.], shape=(6,), dtype=float64)
    d = tf.cast(tf.shape(y)[-1], tf.float64)  # tf.Tensor(6.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
    # _get_indices(interpolation)
    indices = tf.round(
        (d - 1) * frac_at_q_or_above
    )  # tf.Tensor(2.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
    indices = tf.clip_by_value(
        tf.cast(indices, tf.int32), 0, tf.shape(y)[-1] - 1
    )  # tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
    # N.B. The sort order here is descending, causing a difference
    gathered_y = tf.gather(
        sorted_y, indices, axis=-1
    )  # tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
    result = distribution_util.rotate_transpose(gathered_y, tf.rank(q))  # 4.0
    print(f"Result of tf.percentile source: {result}")


def main():
    np_in = np.array([[10.0, 7.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
    numpy_src(np_in, q=50)
    tf_in = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_in)
    tensorflow_src(tf_in, q=50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which when run gives

```
$ python answer.py 
Result of np.percentile source: 3.0
Result of tf.percentile source: 4.0
```

If *instead* there was the following added to TensorFlow Probability's `percentile` to make the sort order of the evaluation *ascending*

```py
sorted_y = tf.reverse(
    sorted_y, [-1]
)  # tf.Tensor([ 1.  2.  3.  4.  7. 10.], shape=(6,), dtype=float64)
```

then the two results would be the same

```
$ python answer.py 
Result of np.percentile source: 3.0
Result of tf.percentile source: 3.0
```

Given that TensorFlow Probability's [docstring](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile) says

> Given a vector `x`, the `q`-th percentile of `x` is the value `q / 100` of the way from the minimum to the maximum in a sorted copy of `x`.

this seems wrong, as it is giving the reverse of that. I've opened [TensorFlow Probability Issue 864](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/864) to discuss this.